# How to use some as the filter callback in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am trying to filter an array using the some function as a callback and have only elements which are multipliers of the other array.

```
function sumOfNumbersDivisibleByAnyFunctional(upTo) {
  var numbers = [];
  for(var i = 0;i<=upTo; i +=1){
    numbers.push(i);
  }
  function filterByArr(arr){
    return function (el){
      return arr.some(multiplier => el % multiplier === 0);
    }
  }
return numbers.filter(filterByArr(arguments));
}
```

But no matter how I tried I am getting an error saying the `arr.some` is not a function.
Any idea what I am missing?

I also tried:

```
return numbers.filter(noToTest => arguments.some(multiplier => noToTest % multiplier === 0));
```

If this is called:

```
sumOfNumbersDivisibleByAnyFunctional(10,3,5)
```

it will create an array of numbers between 0-10 and return only ones that are multipliers of 3 or 5.

I don't this this should be closed as duplicate of `How can I convert the “arguments” object to an array in JavaScript?`. As mentioned this is the issue with the code above but does not answer the original question. for reference I would leave the question open and post n answer explaining the correct solution.

Comment: Can you share some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: "error saying the arr.some is not a function. Any idea what I am missing?" — You're missing an array. `arr` isn't one.

Comment: `arguments` is not an array, it does't have `some` method

Comment: Just change your `filterByArr()` method to `function filterByArr(arr){
  arr = Array.from(arr);
  arr.shift();
  return function (el){
    return Array.from(arr).some(multiplier => el % multiplier === 0);
  }
}`

Comment: And don't declare function statements inside other functions. Use function expressions `var fn = function() { blah, blah }`.

Comment: Please, can you provide an example of input data and desired result (filtered data)?

Comment: issue was solved by @Quentin, the issue is not with the filter or some function but with the way to work with `arguments`. when the last line is changed to `numbers.filter(filterByArr([].slice.call(arguments)));` it works as expected.

Comment: @JaredSmith — There is nothing wrong with using a function declaration inside a function

Comment: @Quentin `filteredByArray` is declared inside `sumOfNumbersDivisibleByAnyFunctional`. It's just hard to tell because of the lack of formatting. As for whether or not that's a good idea, YMMV.